# Different workbooks, same macro names and activation shortcuts

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 `Workbooks`. They contain different data and sheets, but have some **same macro names**, which are being ran by the **same keybord shortcuts**.
For example: both have `Sub ArrangeTitles()` macro which is being called by `Ctrl+Shift+R`. The vba codes inside these Subs are different.

The problems start when **both Workbooks are open** and the user presses 
`Ctrl+Shift+R`, which sometimes **runs the wrong Sub** (the "other Workbook's Sub"), and this is according to the order of opening the Workbooks.

My goal is to be able to activate the **right macro** which belongs to the **right Workbook**, without changing any names or shortcuts.

I have looked for a solution for this all around the web with no success.
So I figured out some-kind of bypass solution which works well.
I will soon add the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

The Solution is based on attaching each `macro` to its `ActiveWorkbook.Name`.

For each Workbook, and every "problematic" macro (for example: my `Sub ArrangeTitles`), do the following:

**At Excel "View" tag -> Macros:**

1. Disconnect the `Sub ArrangeTitles` from its keyboard activation `Ctrl+Shift+R`.

**At the VBA Code:**

2. Optional: change the `ArrangeTitles` `Sub` into `Function`.
3. Optional: Add new Module to contain al my new "connection Subs" such as the following:
4. Add:

> ```
> Sub Ctrl_Shift_R()
>     Dim strPath As String
>     strPath = "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'" & "!ArrangeTitles"  ' The target macro within it's current wWorkbook
>     Application.Run (strPath)
> End Sub
> ```

**And back to Excel "View" tag -> Macros:**

5. Connect the `macro Ctrl_Shift_R` to the keyboard activation: Ctrl+Shift+R.
6. Save.
7. Instruct the user to click somewhere in the workbook before using Ctrl+Shift+R.